# Can my starter Pokemon be shiny?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I have not played Pokemon since Red/Blue/Yellow and all of this shiny stuff is new to me. I have just started playing Pokemon X and I am wondering if you can get a shiny version of the starter pokemon. (ie: before I spend a lot of time trying to get this I would like to know if its possible.)

Additional Info: I know you can find shiny versions of the starter pokemon by looking around for them or what not. I am asking specifically about the starter pokemon themselves. (The ones you get when sitting at the table with the four other people)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is always a chance that a generated pokemon will be shiny. So yes a 'starter' starter pokemon CAN be shiny with the same 1 in 8192 chance as usual. But if you want a shiny you are MUCH better off trying to get a female and breeding it later. You get the Day-care very soon after the first badge so you are no longer halfway through the game before you can breed a pokemon you want.

Comment: You are even better off, if the breeding partner for your female starter is from a game with a different language than your female, e.g. Japanese x English. [See: Masuda Method](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Breeding#Breeding_for_Shininess). Chances are 5 - 6 times better then.

Answer (score 4):

Like other Pokemon, there is a 1 in 8192 chance for the starter pokemon to be a shiny. Just reset over and over until you get it.