# What is the CP of the starter Pokémon? Mine had 13, is that always the case?

Tags: pokemon-go

I found two related questions to this already: [Can my starter Pokemon be shiny?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136498/can-my-starter-pokemon-be-shiny) and [Can you start with Pikachu in Pokemon Go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272835/can-you-start-with-pikachu-in-pokemon-go)

I wondered that it is not an even number and so I guessed everybody has a different CP with the starter Pokémon. And in the case it's always the 13, do Pikachu or a shiny starter have a higher or a lower CP?

Comment: Note that your linked "Can my starter Pokemon be shiny?" question is NOT about pokemon go, rather it is about one of the DS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My starter Pokemon had a CP of 10, a buddy of mine had his starter with a CP of 14, so it seems that it differs a bit, but not by much.

Answer (score 1):

my Bulbasaur has a CP of 14, and it's CP bar is at the absolute minimum.

I wonder if it varies depending on which you choose?

Answer (score -2):

I think it depends on which one you choose, and also your location, like a water Pokemon would be more powerful near a source of water.